# how can I hide params I transmit to a method (like form_for seems to do)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, hide, parameters

I've been searching for hours now and haven't found anything that helps.

### What I want to do:

I need to call the `check_login`-Method (as below), which needs parameters.

```
redirect_to check_login_users_url(
  :user => {:name => input[1], :password => input [2] },
  :stylesheet => 'scaffold',
  :method => :get)
```

The point is that these params are sent in the method-call as in the "Redirected to"-line below.

```
Processing ApplicationController#execute(for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-12-19 00:28:40) [POST]
Parameters: {"command"=>{"line"=>"log dodo wg"}, "authenticity_token"=> <...token>}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/benutzer/check_login?method=get&stylesheet=scaffold&user%5Bname%5D=dodo&user%5Bpassword%5D=wg
Completed in 9ms (DB: 0) | 302 Found [http://localhost/execute]
```

---

**I want to prevent rails from putting the params into the url and pass them hidden instead.**

When I send a form created with `form_for`, there's nothing in the url, so I assume it must be possible.

*Please tell me how to do that.*

---

### Steps tried

- I have tried different "html-verbs": get, put, post - no difference. Though the call of `check_login` is really short the url-with-params shows up in my Console
- create an instance variable and pass it as param (strange, didn't work either)
- watch `form_for` working – without results, got no clue

---

---

***//edith:***
Thanks for all your help so far. Perhaps I didn't specify my problem in enough detail. 
I've got a `text_field` in which I enter short commands (experimentally). Its form calls `execute` in `AppController`, which in case of login-data performs `redirect_to` `check_login`. I don't need to access a webpage, I simply want to run the method. I liked the idea of putting it into `:flash`, but I'm wondering if there's a "neater" way to do pass the data hidden.

Comment: That looks like debugging output to me. Run it in production mode and see if it still shows up in your logs.

Comment: @NSD: You're right, but it's not the logs that disturb me. If I'm lucky I can see the url-with-params in my browser, too. `form_for` doesn't do that – but how?

Comment: It uses POST requests. Look at the sources yourself.

Comment: Wouldn't that be better as a before_filter? That's how all the authentication plugins handle this kind of thing.

Comment: @EmFi: what are you refering to? What should I do in a before_filter?

Answer (score 4):

**TL; DR Version:** Use a form.

You're never going to be able to fully hide parameters, tools can be used to monitor requests and view the post data/parameters. You could however obfuscate it with an encrypted session. Also it appears that you're sending login info via a GET request, this is generally a bad practice.

That said...

What is going wrong for you is that you're not generating any post data with link_to :method => :post. link_to will use what ever parmas you give it to generate the url. Wheres forms will send all the params generated by the form as POST data to the url generated in the form_for call.

Upon receiving a POST request, Rails will merge parameters routing picks up from from the URL with the post data it receives into one params hash.

As in POST to

```
http://localhost:3000/benutzer/check_login?stylesheet=scaffold&user%5Bname%5D=dodo&user%5Bpassword%5D=wg
```

produces the same params hash in the receiving controller action as a POST to `http://localhost:3000/benutzer/check_login` with the following data:

```
 stylesheet=scaffold&user[name]=dodo&user[pasword]=wg
```

There will be no distinction in the server log between the two requests.

If you look at what form_for is doing, it submits POST data built from the form inputs to the url generated by the arguments.

```
form_for @user, create_user_url(:stylesheet => "scaffold") do |f|
  f.text_field :name
  f.password_field, :password
end
```

This form will submit the form data to the url generated from the options. In this example the url is: `http://localhost:3000/users/create?stylesheet=scaffold` and the form data is:

```
user[name]=name_field_value_at_submit&user[password]=password_field_value_at_submit
```

link_to will not populate post data for you. You must either do it through a form or with javascript. The [link_to documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001597) contains an example of doing this with javascript. Look for how the destroy with :onclick is handled.

If you really don't like buttons, you could use link_to_function to submit a form.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
:method => :get)
```

with

```
:method => :post)
```

What's the difference between `:get` and `:post`?  Read [Methods GET and POST in HTML forms - what's the difference?](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html)

Comment: Unluckily, that doesn't help. Of course I read about GET and POST & co, but it makes no difference for my call. Where `Redirected to` says `...check_login?method=get...` it says `method=post` when I replace "get".

Comment: You're going to have to do something besides call redirect_to in order to make a POST request.

Comment: As I now clarified my question – can you tell me what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

With `form_for` you create form which is  then `POST`ed to server, that's why you don't see parameters in url - they're in http request body. But it is not possible to redirect user's browser from some action in controller to make another `POST` - if it would be possible, then I could redirect user to (for example) email change form of gmail or other forms. You can only redirect user to other site, which user's browser then `GET`s.

If you really don't want to show parameters in url, and both actions are in same application, then you can store those parameters in `session` or `flash` store, and retrieve in next request after redirect.

Comment: It works! (with `flash`)
.
But is there no other way I can invoke `check_login` with params? Usually the `login`-form on a page calls `check_login` as `:action` and it doesn't have params in the url then. So why can't I?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Ajax request to send form data to action** :

In some cases its not good to change **:get** into **:post**.

For instance in case of Controller's **:index** action its not good approach to use **:post**

**So Use ajax call to submit form and update only dynamic content of the page.**

In js.coffe script file

```
$ ->
  $("#button-id").on "click", (ev) ->

  $.ajax
    type: "GET"
    dataType: "html"
    url: "/horoscope_dailies"
    data:
      date: date
    success: (data) ->
      $("#index_content").html data
    error: (object, error) ->
      console.log error
```

In your controller action

```
render partial: 'partial_name' if request.xhr?
```

In your view file:

```
%div{:id => 'partial_content'} 
  = render 'partial_name'
```