# How to hide the id pass from controller in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

localhost:3000/c_g/edit_items?id=1

Hi..i have a problem to route the system. I dont want to show the id=1 that pass from view to controller for security issue. So how to hide it? so it will be like this

localhost:3000/c_g/edit_items

Comment: Let's try this: why is that a security issue?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Fine... get to the root of the problem :)

Comment: Jesse is right, the id should not be sensitive data. Also, while it is always the developers choice, I must recommend that you read up on RESTful routes - Rails is all about convention.

Comment: it's because the user can change the id from id=1 into id=2. Then the value of id=2 will appear. that is my problem. maybe you all have a solution in that case? sorry. actually i'm new in rails. so have many things to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931364/how-can-i-hide-params-i-transmit-to-a-method-like-form-for-seems-to-do) it looks like you might want to explore doing it as a POST. Alternatively you could try the [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem and go for some sort of obfuscation. A simpler form of that is suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623017/hide-user-id-in-the-url-bar) but again it is more obfuscation than full omission.