# Ruby on rails parameters are appearing in the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, parameter-passing, url-parameters

Hi im having two actions `check` and `display` in my `controller` and i have two views `check.html.erb` and `display.html.erb` in the view corresponding to those actions. The check method has a form in it's view 
Here is the check.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :display_command_list, :method => "get", :url => {:action => "display"} do |f| %>
                  <%= f.label :username %>
                  <%= f.text_field :username %><br />
                  <%= f.label :password %>
                  <%= f.password_field (:password) %><br />
                  <%= f.submit "Submit"%>
                <% end%>
```

Below are both the actions:

```
def check
end

def display
#some code here
respond_to do |format|
format.html
end
end
```

When i fill the form in check view, it submits the form the display action and display action redirects to display view. But the problem is /display.html.erb is having all the parameters submitted in the form in it's url like this - `/display?%username%=myname`... I think my check method needs something to be written in it so that the form is submitted to display method and the url does not contain the parameters in the form. 
I cannot use the parameters in the check method using params as they are empty and it throws a nil object error
Please help

Update:

I used a :method => post instead of a :method=> get in the form_for tag after seeing 
[how can I hide params I transmit to a method (like form_for seems to do)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931364/how-can-i-hide-params-i-transmit-to-a-method-like-form-for-seems-to-do)

and it does not show any parameters in url. 
But now when i go to another view from display.html.erb (say do_something.html.erb) and click on back button to come back to my display.html.erb, it says the web page expired.

Please let me know if iam not clear in asking the question or if iam doing something obviously wrong here..

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you like having parameters in url? That's standard practice. Anyway you should either use POST and face some issues with browser behavior (like returning back to the page as you described or Ctrl-R-ing the page) or use GET and have all parameters in the url. That's how HTTP works.

Comment: The parameters are having username and passwords and i dont wish anyone to see the user name and passwords

Comment: Then you should use the POST request and get the warnings. I'm feeling you're doing something wrong though. Instead of validating your action each time, maybe it will be better to implement some kind  of authentication system (i recommend Devise).